# Changing the CSSOM css style properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, cssom

I am trying to use style.cssText to display hidden paragraphs using javascript. Here is my code:

html:

```
<p class="toy-pictures-latest">Latest Toy Pictures</p>
         <p class="toy-pictures-greatest">Greatest Toy Pictures</p>
```

css:

```
.toy-pictures-latest{
    display: none;
}

.toy-pictures-greatest{
        display: none;
}
```

js:

```
toy-pictures-latest.style.cssText = 'display: inline;';
```

I have also tried

```
document.getElementById("toy-pictures-latest").style.cssText = 'display: inline;';
```

Please see the codepen:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/j354374/pen/zYqjjaq)

Please let me know how I should be approaching this problem.

Comment: Something like this? document.getElementById("toy-pictures-latest").style.display = "inline";

Comment: Yes: `style.display = 'inline'`

Comment: I tried it in a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/j354374/pen/XWdqqQj)

I get: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: Is that you are using 'getElementById', but in the elements you use class and not id

Comment: Use: `document.querySelector('.toy-pictures-greatest').style.display = 'inline'`

Comment: I changed my classes to ids and it's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

js:

```
document.getElementById("toy-pictures-latest").style.display = "inline";
```

html:

```
<p id="toy-pictures-latest">Latest Toy Pictures</p>
```

css:

```
#toy-pictures-latest{
    display: none;
}
```